# Log-concavity inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, convexity

Let $x,y,$ and $t$ be fixed real numbers, $1<x<y$, $0<t<1$. Does the following inequality hold for some $c$

$$\frac{\log{(tx+(1-t)y)}}{\log^t{x}\log^{(1-t)}{y}}>\frac{\log{(sw+(1-s)z)}}{\log^s{w}\log^{(1-s)}{z}}$$

for $1<x<y\leq w<z$, $|z-w|\leq c|y-x|$, $c>0$, and $0<s<1$?

Intuition says this is true since $\log$ becomes ''flatter'' as its argument grows, so that the ratio on the right hand side should be closer to one when $z$ and $w$ are larger. Also how large can $c$ become?

**Edit**: I can more or less see how to do this with crude error bounds. I guess I am curious if there are simpler ways of seeing this.

Comment: Is there no connection between $s$ and $t$?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Nope. $t$ is just fixed, while $s$ free to vary.

Comment: Since $c$ doesn't appear in the inequality and $|z-w|\le c|y-z|$ is true for some $c>0$, it seems that condition is irrelevant.  Or did you omit an upper bound on $c$?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay It should hold for some fixed $c$ depending on the $x,y$ and $t$. I'm interested in larger $c$. Also, if the $z$ and $w$ become spaced out enough one can find counterexamples to the inequality. Maybe this clarifies things?

Comment: Yes, it clarifies that the problem statement needs clarifying. If it is only true for some $c$, you have say "for some $c$" or "there exists $c$ such that".

Comment: Are the brackets missed in the numerators?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, the convex combinations are within the logarithms.

Comment: May $c$ depend on $x, y, t$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yeah, it should, I expect.

Comment: How do you understand the deniminators if $x<1$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I will adjust it to $x>1$ for this reason.

Comment: The second derivative of $\log\log x$ is decreasing, so just compare it with $2$ parabolas with the same leading coefficient, in which case the optimal $c$ is just $2\sqrt{t(1-t)}$ if I haven't screwed my algebra.

Comment: @fedja Thanks! I think it could be true for larger $c$, but I will check the details.

Comment: No, that's the limit: If the differences are small or you are far away from the origin, then the second derivative doesn't change noticeably and $\log\log x$ is indistinguishable from a parabola in the range you are interested in (I assume you want a uniform bound in $x,y,z,w$).

Comment: @fedja Yes, absolutely. I had an application in mind where the $z>>x$ which had me thinking otherwise. Thanks again.